# 2 input on a directive in angular

Tags: angular

I have a directive in angular 11 with the following inputs :

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appHasToken]",
})
export class HasTokenDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input("appHasToken") fallback: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input("showWarning") showWarning = false;
//...
}
```

I call it in my code like this :

```
<ng-container *appHasToken="noToken">
```

Now in a single place, I want the showWarning to true, so I did

```
<ng-container *appHasToken="noToken;" [showWarning]="true">
```

but I am prompted with

> Can't bind to 'showWarning' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

now, I know I can rename the input with a different name than the directive and do

```
<ng-container appHasToken [templateRef]="noToken" [showWarning]="true">
```

but what about keeping the same stuff I was doing, is there a fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a directive with * (structural directive), angular adds an ng-template around your element, so `<ng-container *appHasToken="noToken">` gets translated to:

```
<ng-template [appHasToken]="noToken">
  <ng-container></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

When you have another input, the second input remains on the ng-container, and since the directive isn't there anymore, angular throws because the now ng-container doenst have a known property `showWarning`. To overcome this, there is microsyntax in angualr which allows passing more than one input to the structural directive - you add the directive name in the input naming before the input's name, so `showWarning` becomes `appHasTokenShowWarning` (notice the uppercase in the first word), and then can be accessed in the following way:

```
<ng-container *appHasToken="noToken; showWarning true">
```

if this reminds you of `ngFor` its because `ngFor` also uses this! here is the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts)

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directive-with-two-inputs?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftwo-inputs-directive.directive.ts), and note your inputs should look like the following:

export class HasTokenDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
@Input("appHasToken") fallback: TemplateRef;
@Input("appHasTokenShowWarning") showWarning = false;
//...
}

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried to do this before : `*appHasToken="noToken; showWarning: true"` but it makes the whole thing invalid 

>Property binding appHasTokenShowWarning not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".

Comment: while `*appHasToken="noToken"` alone works, I don7t know why the addition breaks the whjole thing.

Comment: and you also changed the input name in the directive?

Comment: the inputs names are like the main post.

Comment: you have to change the input for the second parameter, read my answer again, I will add a stackblitz in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

`<ng-container>` isn't rendered in the DOM. It is mainly used as Javascript curly braces in the template for *ngFor and *ngIf. Check the documentation  https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

Instead, use a plain div or any other component.